# NoClassDef error after adding in Jar to send email

Tags: java, android, email, android-studio, classpath

I've been troubleshooting for a while and may be suffering from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so this will be fairly descriptive.

**Goal:** Send a simple email message on the click of a button without leveraging external mail app.

Research led to the [JavaMail API](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home), which was successfully compiled, tested, and executed on a personal computer.

So after spending some time reading answers here I followed these steps to add the library.

1. Right click on App -> New Module -> Import .JAR/.AAR Package.
2. Utilize ellipsis button to find and add the jar.
3. App -> Module Settings
4. Under Modules, App -> Dependencies -> Add -> Module Dependency -> Selecting the JAR module.

In addition to this, I also did the following:

1. Ensured the app module's build.gradle included the dependency (In this case, listed as compile project(':javax.mail')
2. On project root, use and run `gradlew clean` as well as `gradlew build`

This has been tried a few other, failing ways but these are the latest series of steps. Android Studio detects the files, but when executed the app crashes with a `NoClassDefFoundError`. Intuition says the problem is classpath but after trying several different but ineffective solutions for this it's time to yield to more experienced advice.

For reference:

**MainActivity:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emailButton);
        testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Emailer.send(getApplicationContext());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Emailer:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class Emailer {
    public static void send(Context context) {
        // Recipient's email
        String recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";

        // Sender information
        String sender = "myemail@gmail.com";
        final String username = "myUsername";
        final String password = "myPassword";

        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {
            // constructing the email
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
            message.setSubject("Email Test");
            message.setText("Testing the email capability using JavaMailAPI on Android");

            // Sending
            Transport.send(message);
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.email_success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```